# How to write a production rule for the power set of a given set

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, grammar

I am writing a small command language. The language has a few simple commands, which can be composed to make complex ones. For example, if we have commands `fry an egg`, `make a sandwich`, `make coffee`, we can create a new command :

`make a breakfast := fry an egg, make a sandwich, make coffee`.

However sometimes, I want only coffee for breakfast, sometimes both coffee and sandwich, etc. That is, `make a breakfast` can be any subset of commands set: `{fry an egg, make a sandwich, make coffee}`

Thus I need a rule to define a power set of a given set of simple commands. Does it make sense ? Can I do that ?

Comment: It makes sense to me, and you can probably do that.  But it's difficult to say more without seeing some portion of your existing grammar and/or example code to be parsed.

Comment: What do you mean by a "rule"?  What sort of parser are you using?  Your example has a flaw:  I can't fry two eggs.  Does that limitation need to be baked into the parser?  Fundamentally, I don't know how to write a power set rule for parsers I'm halfway familiar with, and I don't know why I'd want to.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use (E)BNF grammar notation. If your question is about how to capture powerset in a grammar rule. AFAIK (E)BNF allows only to describe context-free grammars, however the powerset can be modeled as a language {a^2^n} in alphabet {a}, which is context sensitive. This means, you cannot use (E)BNF to describe any powerset. However what you can do, is to enumerate the specific powerset. For example: 
S := (a,{b, {c}}|(b, {c})|c|epsilon);
This language is powerset of the {a,b,c} alphabet.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel. I see that the power set can be described by a context free grammar. It is interesting though how it can be modeled anyway.